# jQuery cycle-What's stopping the slide and why isn't animate() working?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-animate, slideshow

I have a 5 photos slideshow running, and I want to do an animate() function when it slides to the 4th photo. Instead of running the animate();, the slideshow stops when it slides to the 4th one. What's going on??

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('#slideshow').cycle({
    fx:       'fadeZoom',
    timeout:   2000,
    pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {
        // return sel string for existing anchor
        return '#nav li:eq(' + (idx) + ') a';
    } ,
    after:     onAfter,
});
});

function onAfter(curr,next,opts) {
var caption = (opts.currSlide + 1);
$('#caption').html(caption);
var number = $('#caption').html();
if(caption == "4"){
     $('#nav_content').animate({
            left: pos.left - 180
            }, 500);
        };
};
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you reproduce this with a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Hi David, Im not sure how to use it but i manage to upload the page to a friend's server  [link](http://coreltest.peekaboo.com.tw) . On the page my "Next" and "Prev" button were working fine as well, but once the slide reaches the 4th photo they just stopped working. I know there must be something wrong with the line `if(caption == "4")...` but don't know how to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: If you look at the JavaScript console of your browser you'll see the error: 'Uncaught ReferenceError: pos is not defined' So I suspect the problem is with the `pos` variable.

Comment: Omg, thanks so much. It works now !! Sorry I'm quite new to all this coding, how do one check the Javascript error using the browser? Again, thx so much David!!

Comment: It depends on what browser you're using, but the JavaScript console's usually under the tools menu somewhere; in Chromium/Chrome you can use the keyboard short-cut `ctrl` + `shift` + `i` and then click on the 'console' tab.

Comment: Also, if you did something to make it work, please post the changes you made as an answer to this question, that way someone with the same, or similar, error might be able to save some time in future and find a useful resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot the define the variable "pos" in the function. Now it works as expected.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('#slideshow').cycle({
    fx:       'fadeZoom',
    timeout:   2000,
    pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {
        // return sel string for existing anchor
        return '#nav li:eq(' + (idx) + ') a';
    } ,
    after:     onAfter,
});
});

function onAfter(curr,next,opts) {
var caption = (opts.currSlide + 1);
$('#caption').html(caption);
var number = $('#caption').html();
var c = $('#nav_content');
    var pos = c.position();
    var w = c.width();
    var status = w + pos.left;
    var dif = w - 190;
    var x = w + dif;
if(caption == "4"){
     $('#nav_content').animate({
            left: pos.left - 180
        }, 500);
    };
    if(caption == "1" & pos.left < 0){
     $('#nav_content').animate({
            left: pos.left + 180
        }, 500);
    };
};
```